# Detecting browser/version with javascript vs. detecting on server side?

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache, http

We are building a bookmarklet, and we are wondering if we can detect on client side with JavaScript the browser and version number more accurately than doing that on server side using the agent.

We would push the detection results to the server for the main request.

The questions is, can this approach work better and be more accurate? Or both can do the same mistakes and JavaScript itself computes from the user-agent (which can be changed by plugin/proxy).

**IMPORTANT**

Please don't forget that we are building a **bookmarklet** and so we can't load fancy tools like Modernizr and JQuery as it doesn't work out fast.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to want to know the users browser... imo none of the feature detection nazi's have answered this legitimate question. Good post about some best of class impls from some industry standard toolsets: http://robert.accettura.com/blog/2009/11/30/browser-detection-in-javascript-libraries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think that JS also uses the user agent. So far I haven't seen a JS browser detect code that doesn't compute from the user agent. Correct me if I am wrong. If this helps you try the JQuery `$.support` property for detection/support for particular features that you need rather than relying on browser name and version. It is easy to fake your user-agent.

According to the [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml) the `navigator` object uses the user-agent header.

Comment: `jQuery.support` do not use userAgent , however if you rely on using userAgent then **jQuery.browser** and **jQuery.browser.version** can be used. Both of these use `userAgent` .

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to detect the user agent? Are you going to run different javascript dependent on the user agent? JQuery and or Mootools provides an abstraction tier that takes care of different browser JS. Additionally, media queries and other API's can detect things like viewport size, resolution etc to faciliate content adaption. If you want to serve totally different resources to different user agents, then server side content negotiation is preferable. In this case, you can detect the browser features from a user agent string using something like the Apache Mobile Filter (built upon the WURFL device repository).

Finally, if you want to make sure that the network / proxy doesn't tamper with your request, then use the following directive in the following HTTP request and response header:

```
Cache-Control: no-transform
```

This can be set prior to an AJAX request using JQuery (or simply setting on the XmlHttpRequest object) and can also be set in your Apache configuration for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't detect browser, but detect available features instead, unless your entire task boils down to exactly that - like detecting browsers from some statistical purposes or there's some specific issue for some browser that successfully report supporting a feature, but doesn't really support it or is flawed (think IE6's PNG support). [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and the like can help you with feature detection, if you don't want to code it by hand.

If you still want browser detection, then yes, you have more opportunities from client-side JS than from server. On server you only limited to analyzing User-Agent header that can be stripped or mangled by either proxy or in client itself, but in JS, in addition to examining user agent string, you can also detect presence of browser-specific objects in environment or check browser-specific quirks in implementation of some features to accurately detect what browser you really in. The single drawback though is that, naturally, user must have JS enabled.

As a simple example, checking if you have access to `ActiveXObject`, will tell you that you're in Internet Explorer and checking if there's native `JSON.parse` available can show if it is version 7 in standard mode or older/compatibility mode instead, no matter what how much user agent string is mangled.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: Except for `navigator.appVersion` and `navigator.userAgent`, the rest are completely unusable (e.g., Chrome returns "Netscape" for `navigator.appName`)